# Typescript array to string union

Tags: typescript

I need to convert array to string union. See below

```
export class Foo<K extends string[]> {
    make<L extends string[]>(keys: L): Foo<L> {
        return new Foo();
    }
    get(key: K) {

    }
}

const x = Foo.make(['a', 'b'])

// need to constraint this to 'a' | 'b'
x.get('')
```

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is capturing the string literals when you call `make`. You could do this in one of several ways. You could use tuples in rest parameters (`make<L extends string[]>(...keys: L): Foo<L>` but this will require you call the `make` function as `Foo.make('a', 'b')`.

Another option is to use the fact that the compiler will preserve literal types if they are assigned to a type parameter constrained to `string`. This will preserve the current way of calling.

The issue of getting the union is simple, you can use a [type query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).

```
export class Foo<K extends string[]> {
    static make<L extends V[], V extends string>(keys: L): Foo<L> {
        return new Foo();
    }
    get(key: K[number]) { // index type

    }
}

const x = Foo.make(['a', 'b'])

x.get("a")
x.get("A") // err
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=13&ssc=18&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DEIQDwDScoMwAdgCaZoxQCWZA5gNoC6AfHAN4CwAUHEFwaKGHQRwAtigDWwPABliIUpUwA1NgBo465aqrDaDRuwAUcgJ5oAXHAUBKOznwLOvAUK9RgMAK5QZHBkwADu2LhmDgDc-F4AvnFCjL4WwJZ2BMxkfpIARsBQrA7ccAD0ZXAMFKBwMJZgwPxJgol8bfwIEGQ0cCBwALwREAB00nJmzADkKFM6U3lTxc18ICMpMGYARChbDvxrG9sAgnvllYVQQA)

Another option is not to use the tuple type in `L`, just capture the union directly when calling `make`:

```
export class Foo<K extends string> {
    static make<V extends string>(keys: V[]): Foo<V> {
        return new Foo();
    }
    get(key: K) { // index type

    }
}

const x = Foo.make(['a', 'b'])

x.get("a")
x.get("A") // err
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=13&ssc=18&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DEIQDwDScoMwAdgCaZoxQCWZA5gHxwDeAsAFBy9w0oYdBHAC2KANbA8ANWIhSlarQYsAFFICeaAFxwZAbQC6ASj058M1px587UYDACuUMnDLAA7tlxqTAbm47AF8gvkZHDWBNPQITdjgAekS4BgpQOBhNMGBuMN5QrkLuBAgyGjgQOABeHwgAOnEpNQMAchRWgBo4VoAjVtM8rhB6iJg1ACIUCZNuEbHJgEEZpJTgKCggA)

Comment: thanks it works, it is little bit tricky i have to compile the tricks in my mind :) i understand that if it is exactly string that it accepts anything, but how comes that extends string works another way. it means that it must be V a V is 'a' | 'b' but if V extends string it doesnt mean anything as well? you get my question.

Comment: @luky It is just the defined compiler behavior.. before `as const` it was one of the few ways to hint to the compiler you want literal types... TS has multiple such 'constraints that hint'